# Combining string from csv into one line

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read from csv file that only has one column. I need to combine all of the string into one for instance `Row[1]=="Hallo."` and `Row[2]=="Goodbye."` into `string=="Hallo. Goodbye."`.

```
import csv

data=None
with open('reviews.csv',encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        data2=(row[0])
        print(f'\n{data}.')
        line_count += 1
        data+=data2
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Current error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I have searched and read few posts but cannot seem to understand it.

Comment: You're being presented with a type error. Change `data` from None type to an empty string: `data=''`

Comment: @chb He would still need to check the type of the variable, so it would be more efficient to simply forgo concatenating it if it is of type NoneType, especially since concatenating an empty string won't actually do anything.

Comment: how many rows you have ??

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I have 10 rows

Comment: I wasn't paying attention @chb You were referring to him needing to initialize it - my bad

Comment: The first iteration of the loop, `data` is `None`. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but that's the cause of the error.

Comment: Replace `data = None` with `data = ''`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are joining a bunch of strings, try using the join method of a string with a simple generator comprehension:

```
import csv

with open('reviews.csv',encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    data = "".join(row[0] for row in csv_reader if isinstance(row[0], str))

print(data)
print(f'Processed {csv_reader.line_num} lines')
```

Note that csv_reader internally keeps track of how many lines it has reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a test file to work with.

```
with open("/tmp/junk.txt", 'w') as f: 
    for i in range(10): 
        f.write("Hello {}\n".format(i))
```

Now open your file.

```
with open("/tmp/junk.txt", 'r') as f: 
    data = f.readlines()
```

Clean up the whitespace (trailing new lines).

```
data = [i.strip() for i in data]
```

And finally join it back together, space delimited.

```
print(" ".join(data))                                                                                                                                                          
Hello 0 Hello 1 Hello 2 Hello 3 Hello 4 Hello 5 Hello 6 Hello 7 Hello 8 Hello 9
```

Answer (score 0):

A file with one column isn't a CSV.  It is just a file with lines.  To join up all the lines:

```
with open('reviews.csv') as f:
    print(' '.join(f.read().splitlines()))
```